# AWK: Use First Line's Info to prepend each line

Tags: bash, awk

I have an awk 1 liner inside of a bash script. 
Need help with doing an awk line... 
Here's what I tried, but doesn't work.

here's my data.vcf

```
. abc hji ran kls
CHR1 0/0 0/0 0/1 0/0
CHR2 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0
CHR3 1/1 0/0 0/0 0/0
CHR4 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1
```

Code I have so far (Other bash code is unrelated):

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) { if ($i ~ "/1") print NR==1 $i," ",$0} }' data.vcf
```

this prints:

```
 . abc hji ran kls
 0 CHR1 0/0 0/0 0/1 0/0
 0 CHR2 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0
 0 CHR3 1/1 0/0 0/0 0/0
 0 CHR4 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1
```

I would like it to print this:

```
 . abc hji ran kls
 ran CHR1 0/0 0/0 0/1 0/0
 abc CHR2 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0
 abc CHR3 1/1 0/0 0/0 0/0
 kls CHR4 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1
```

Basically, just prepend $i from the awk command with a space included, but using $i for the first line only.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `tesprog.awk` script will give you what you want:

```
NR==1 {
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
        txt[i] = $i;
    }
    print $0;
}
NR > 1 {
    pos = 0;
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i != "0/0") {
            pos = i;
        }
    }
    print txt[pos]" "$0;
}
```

It uses the first record to create an array of the header columns then, for all other records, it looks for the column that *isn't* `0/0` and stores the position.

It then uses that position to look up the text to prefix the line with.

The output from your given test data is:

```
pax> awk -f testprog.awk testprog.in
. abc hji ran kls
ran CHR1 0/0 0/0 0/1 0/0
abc CHR2 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0
abc CHR3 1/1 0/0 0/0 0/0
kls CHR4 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1
```

Now, there *may* be a bit of tweaking required if I haven't quite got the selection criteria right, `if ($i != "0/0")`, but that should be a fairly minimal change. It also selects the *last* matching column if there is more than one possible match so, if that's a possibility, you should specify the behaviour you want in that case.

---

To do this in a `bash` script rather than needing a separate `awk` script, just use:

```
awk '
    NR==1 {
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
            txt[i] = $i;
        }
        print $0;
    }
    NR > 1 {
        pos = 0;
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
            if ($i != "0/0") {
                pos = i;
            }
        }
        print txt[pos]" "$0;
    }' testprog.in
```

or, if you *really* want a one-liner, it'll be a long-ish line, not *quite* as readable as the fully expanded variant:

```
awk 'NR==1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){t[i]=$i}print $0}NR>1{p=0;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if($i!="0/0"){p=i}}print t[p]" "$0}' testprog.in
```

Comment: Hi paxdiablo,  Thank you for your response.  I forgot to mention that the awk 1 liner was part of a bash script, Using your method would I have to create an awk script and incorporate it into my bash script?

Comment: @adrotter, see the update. I did it as a separate script just because I like readability but it can be _just_ as readable within a `bash` script, or slightly less readable if you really need a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an other variation:

```
awk 'NR==1 {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) a[i]=$i;print;next} {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~"/1") $1=a[i]FS$1}1' file
. abc hji ran kls
ran CHR1 0/0 0/0 0/1 0/0
abc CHR2 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0
abc CHR3 1/1 0/0 0/0 0/0
kls CHR4 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1
```

---

How it works:

```
awk '
NR==1 {                     # For line "1"
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)     # Loop trough all elements
        a[i]=$i             # Store them in an array "a" using field location as reference
    print                   # Print the line
    next}                   # Do nothing more with line "1"
    {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)    # Loop trough all fields of all other line
        if ($i~"/1")        # If field location contains "/1"
            $1=a[i]FS$1}    # Use that field number and get information from first line
1                           # Print all out
' file                      # Read the file
```